# Where does macos store 'Others' keyboard layouts? How to delete them?

Tags: macos, keyboard

Where does macos store 'Other' keyboard layouts if they are not in `/Library/Keyboard Layouts` or `~/Library/Keyboard Layouts`?

[image]

Comment: Nothing matching there.

Comment: And not to be argumentative here but why? I do believe a keyboard layout file is a *very* small file, deleting it would not save enough space to be worth running it down?

Comment: I have a duplicate additional layout. Obviously, I don't need both

Comment: @homocomputeris inactive layouts don't interfere with anything

Comment: @TomGewecke Those dirs are empty. Yeah, I know it's tiny. It's just my curiosity and annoyance that it exists somewhere.

Comment: Where did you get РУССКАЯ МАШИНОПИСЬ??  3rd party keyboards like that always go in one of those dirs.

Answer (score 1):

Try the procedure mentioned at the end of [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ukelele-users/PtqnMVzakgc) in the Ukelele list: